# Passing tableViewCell Data Though NavigationsConrtoller to its children from A-> to B-> & to C, using segue Forward

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, uitableview

this error happens when I'm passing data from tabelView cell, the data can be read and used in multiple navigationControllers childrens, I have used segues to pass the data, in the second viewController succesfully, the app crash when prfomSegue to the third viewController `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
the tableViewCell contains this data bellow

```
struct storesData {
    var area: String
    var title: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitued: Double

    static func getAllStores()-> [storesData]{
        return [
            storesData(area: "الخرطوم", title: "KFC", latitude: 15.581010, longitued: 32.569032),

        ]
    }
}
```

this is how I pass the data

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destVC = segue.destination as? Order {
        destVC.stores = sender as? storesData
    } else if let destVC = segue.destination as? GoogleMap {
        destVC.stores = sender as? storesData
    }
```

in the second View controller I'm grabbing the Value of storeData in a variable called stores the navigation title will have the title in the customCell it did work fine

```
var stores: storesData?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            title = stores?.title
    }
```

[image]

this is where the error came out the last data I'm grabbing is the longitude and the latitude of type Double in the third viewCotroller and its view controller with mapView in it I'm using (GoogleMaps)

```
var stores: storesData?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpGoogleMap()

    }

func setUpGoogleMap(){


        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 15.592778, longitude: 32.552278, zoom: 12)
            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
            view.addSubview( mapView)
                mapView.animate(to: camera)
                mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                mapView.delegate = self

        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: stores!.latitude, longitude: stores!.longitued)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.map = mapView


    }
```

[image]

the compiler shows this error

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/mazenqp/Downloads/DELEVARE - ديليفري/DELEVARE - ديليفري/UserinterFace/GoogleMap.swift, line 239
2020-06-07 18:17:35.717618+0200 DELEVARE - ديليفري[17147:915821] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/mazenqp/Downloads/DELEVARE - ديليفري/DELEVARE - ديليفري/UserinterFace/GoogleMap.swift, line 239
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and searching I found an answer, and it did cover most of the cases out there, I just had to change prepare(for:sender) in the first view controller to be like this one

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destVc = segue.destination as? Order,
            let index = storesTV.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            else{return}
        destVc.stores = stores[index]
    }
```

the data get passed successfully to the second VC (Order), and I wright another prepare(for: sender) in Order VC

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVc = segue.destination as? GoogleMap{
            destVc.stores = stores
        }
    }
```

and this is an image shows that the data get passed to the third VC (GoogleMap),
the second and the third Vc they all comes from one navigationController, 
you can find the answer in this article right here
https://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/
[image]